# how to make query in Oracle - like Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access

In access I can make a query (1)  that returns something

and make another query (2)  that uses the first query (1).

How I can do it in Oracle 11g ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What to you want to use the first query for? An insert? An update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert in Oracle but you should check out Views and Nested Views in Oracle.

Comment: can i get sample for nested views ?

Comment: A nested view is just a view that queries another view - in Oracle views can be queried as if they were ordinary tables.

Answer (score 1):

In lack of more information about what to achieve, see the syntax of

- [Insert with Select and Subquery](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/insert/select_and_subquery.html)
- [Update Statements](http://www.psoug.org/reference/update.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your question is, but you can use the WITH clause to create "views" within a query - no need to create a VIEW and in 11g you can use recursive sub-query using the WITH clause.